# How to limit the number of concurrent requests in web api?

Tags: java, web-applications

How to limit by code the number of concurrent requests to web application, say to 3 requests ? Am I suppose to put each servlet class into a thread and create a global counter (by creating new class)?

Comment: No, you configure the webapp server to only have that many request processing threads. E.g. in Tomcat, you set [`maxThreads`](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/http.html#Standard_Implementation).

Comment: That really depends on the Servlet container and/or application-server you are using. The settings will vary. For instance, Tomcat work in two modes: BIO and NIO, you can configure what you want in there, depending on the mode, by setting `maxConnections` and `maxThreads`.

Comment: @Andreas But how can i display to the users that the wed reached its limit (like 3 requests)?

Comment: @ɐuıɥɔɐɯ Where are the maxConnections or maxThreads can be set???

Comment: @student, have a look [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/executor.html). That's for Tomcat `7.x`. You will find it in the Tomcat configuration file, look for the appropriate `<Connector ... />` for your case.

Comment: @ɐuıɥɔɐɯ where in wed.xml should I put <Connector ... />?

Comment: You don't. It goes in `server.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

> How to limit by code the number of concurrent requests to web application, say to 3 requests ? Am I suppose to put each servlet class into a thread and create a global counter (by creating new class)?

You typically rely in the web container to limit the number of concurrent requests; e.g. by setting limit on the number of worker threads or connections ... in the web container configurations.

Apparently, if a Tomcat server gets more requests than it can handle, it will send generic 503 responses.  For more information:

- https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/http.html - explains where / how the configs can be set
- [Tomcat responding HTTP 503](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8825618/) - gives an example of what would happen ...

> But how can i display to the users that the wed reached its limit (like 3 requests)?

If you want to limit specific request types and display specific responses to the user, then you probably will need to implement this within each servlet, using a counter, etcetera.

But the problem with trying to do "nice" things when the server is overloaded is that doing the nice things tends to *increase* the load.  This is particularly important:

- when your server is grossly inadequate for the actual load from (real) users, or
- when someone is DoS'ing you, either accidentally or deliberately.